# Req.body keeps on returning an empty field, even when field is filled out in my form

Tags: node.js, express, post

I have a form where I want to write a comment for my shoe, and then send it to my node.js server through a POST request, but my req.body.comment keeps returning an empty string, even when the comment in my form is filled out.

In my routes file, I have the following line of code:
router.post("/shoe/:id", shoe_controller.shoe_details_post);

and then in my actual shoe controller file, this is how I filled out my shoe_details_post function:

```
exports.shoe_details_post = [
  // Validate and sanitize comment field
  body("comment", "Comment must not be empty.")
    .trim()
    .isLength({ min: 1 })
    .escape(),
  // Process request after validation and sanitization

  asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    // Extract the validation errors from a request.
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    console.log(errors);

    const shoe = Shoe.findById(req.params.id);
    const comment = req.body.comment;

    console.log(req.body);

    // console.log("hi!" + shoe);
    console.log("comment:  " + comment);
    // console.log(req.user);

    res.redirect('/catalog');
  }),
];
```

My form page looks like the following:
extends layout

```
block content
  h1 #{shoe.name}

  img(src=`/images/shoe_images/jordan4.jpeg`)

  form(method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data')
    div.form-group
      label(class="shoe-detail-comment-box" for='comment') Comment:
      textarea#summary.form-control(type='textarea', placeholder='Comment here', name='comment', required='true')
    button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Submit
```

I have another similar method in my shoe_controller file where I did pretty much the exact same thing but for a different form and that works fine, but for some reason this one does not. In my other function, I also validated and sanitized the appropriate fields from my form and was able to get the values of the fields. In this one however, no matter what I do, my comment is always empty.

Comment: Do you have the appropriate middleware installed to read and parse the body of the form post so your request handler can use the info from that?  If not, then that's what you need because that is what populates `req.body`.  If you are really going to use `multipart/form-data` (which would generally only be used when uploading files), then you will need middleware that can handle that content-type.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes I think so. I'm new to node.js and Express. But I am using "express-validator". I also changed the enctype to "text/plain" and I am still encountering the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Express does NOT read the body of any request.  It only reads the headers and leaves the body in the stream waiting for some middleware or request handler that knows how to handle the specific content-type to read and parse the body of the request.  So, your form data is arriving in the body of the request, but you don't specify any Express middleware to read it.  Thus `req.body` remains empty.

To fix this, first off change your form content-type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  `multipart/form-data` can work, but its harder to code on the server and is not needed here (typically used for one or more file uploads when the form thus has multiple parts to the upload, form content plus attached files).

```
block content
  h1 #{shoe.name}

  img(src=`/images/shoe_images/jordan4.jpeg`)

  form(method='POST' action='' enctype='application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    div.form-group
      label(class="shoe-detail-comment-box" for='comment') Comment:
      textarea#summary.form-control(type='textarea', placeholder='Comment here', name='comment', required='true')
    button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Submit
```

Then, you need the appropriate [Express middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded) that reads that content-type.  You would add that like this:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

Make sure this middleware appears BEFORE the request handler for your form.  You only need to specify this once on your Express server as it will apply to all incoming requests that match that content-type.

This will tell express that anytime it finds any requests with a content-type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, that this middleware should read the body of the request, parse it using the expected encoding in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and put the parsed results into `req.body` where the data will then be ready for you in your request handler.  For incoming requests that are not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the middleware will do nothing.

Comment: wow thank you so much! I already had the Express middleware installed, but changing the content-type managed to solve the issue!